# Getting error while using pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, pip

I am trying to install BeautifulSoup to my Python 3.4 on my Windows 8.1. I have already set the `PATH` to `pip` folder. Then I run this command:

```
pip install BeautifulSoup
```

but i get this error:

[image: error pic]

**How can i fix that?**

Comment: You are seeing the error because the syntax is for python 2 where print is a statement as opposed to  a function in python3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because `BeautifulSoup` package maps to [`BeautifulSoup` 3rd version](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/BeautifulSoup/3.2.1) which is not maintained anymore and doesn't support Python3. Quote from it's `PyPI` page:

> This package is OBSOLETE. It has been replaced by the beautifulsoup4
>   package. You should use Beautiful Soup 4 for all new projects.

You need to install the [`beautifulsoup4`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/beautifulsoup4):

```
pip install beautifulsoup4
```